# How to turn numpy array image to bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, google-cloud-platform

I need to recognize image with Google Vision API. Among the examples, they use following construction:

```
with io.open('test.png', 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
```

I need to do similar, but my image comes from:

```
content = cv2.imread()
```

Which returns numpy array, not bytes. I tried:

```
content = content.tobytes()
```

Which converts array to bytes, but returns different bytes apparently, since it gives different result.
So how to make my image array similar to one which I get by `open()` function

Comment: Which bytes do you need? The bytes of the PNG file? The bytes of the decompressed image in RGBA5, RGB8, or RGB16 format depending on what’s in the file? Or specifically in, say, RGB8 no matter how the file was stored? The bytes of the four separate decompressed 16-bit planes in R-G-B-A order? (Little- or big-endian?) Something else?

Comment: @abarnert I don't know exactly. I just want it to look same as as open('file.png', 'rb') gives me. Is there a way to check it?

Comment: Using `open` will give you the compressed version of the image, with header and all.  By looking at the cloud vision API, it expects this stream of bytes and it will infer the kind of image it represents by most likely analyzing the header.  Using `cv2.imread` actually gives you the image representation in a 3D array so the bytes that would be given are what is done after decompression.  EDIT: Use zindarod's answer below.  It actually performs the compression into a memory buffer which you can use to feed into the vision API.

Comment: Then use `encoded_bytes = cv2.imencode('.png', content)`

Comment: @zindarod You should make that a formal answer. That actually achieves what the OP wants.  BTW, the function outputs a tuple with the first element signifying whether encoding was successful (`bool`) and the second element is the actual compressed version of the image.  Suggest you ignore the first element.

Comment: @rayryeng I think the comment will suffice for now. Lets see if helps the OP or not.

Comment: @zindarod Understood... but I'm still confused.  If the OP is using `cv2.imread` where you specify where the image is located... why can't they just simply use `open` on it instead?

Comment: @rayryeng presumably OP is processing the image with OpenCV before sending it through.

Comment: @zindarod whoops, didn't read these comments before posting!

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I suppose it depends on the use case.  If there are image processing operations that can be done on the Cloud API, then perhaps use those instead of relying on something external (OpenCV for example) to do that processing.  I guess there are operations that he can't perform.

Comment: If you’re not actually doing any processing with cv2, decoding a PNG file just to encode that as a PNG again is pretty silly…

Comment: I will process video with opencv, so how should I decode a single frame?

Comment: @wasd OK, now that's different.  That wasn't part of your original question.  You want to feed in a video into the vision API.  That's pretty silly though... the vision API can natively accept video formats.  https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/.  Playing devil's advocate, supposing you want to read in frames from a video - simply take each frame, decode it into the byte representation as seen in the answer below and feed it into the API.  This is a very inefficient way of doing it though as you're decoding and encoding again.

Comment: @rayryeng I don't want to process whole video, it's actually a live stream 24/7. I preprocess some frames and feed them to the analyzer.

Comment: @wasd Oh, so it's from a webcam for instance?  OK, then you can do it this way - you actually don't have a choice then.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds No worries, glad you answered.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You simply need to encode the array in the same format as the image, and *then* use `tobytes()` if you want it in the same format.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> with open('image.png', 'rb') as image_file:
...     content1 = image_file.read()
...
>>> image = cv2.imread('image.png')
>>> success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', image)
>>> content2 = encoded_image.tobytes()
>>> content1 == content2
True
```

Comment: Would it be the same if I will read video? So I will have something like:

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')`

And then work on frames?

Comment: Yes it'll work, but that's a very inefficient way of doing things.  You're decoding the video with OpenCV only to reencode it again in byte form for the cloud vision API.

Comment: content 1 and content 2 are not same for me.

Comment: @pavan with the exact same code here? Or are you using a different encoding (e.g. jpeg)?

Comment: @alkasm I used jpeg.

Comment: @pavan that is why they are different then---the jpeg is a lossy compression format, so the data won't be exactly the same.

Comment: This answer might save hours of your research which I had to face. Thanks @alkasm