# How do I get a TIFF bytestream from an OpenCV image, rather than a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

In python, I want to convert an image that has been processed using OpenCV for transmission in a certain image format (**TIFF** in this case, but could be: BMP, JPEG, PNG, .....).

For this purpose it will suffice to encode the OpenCV image into a memory buffer. The problem is that when I use `cv2.imencode()` to do this the returned object still looks like a `numpy` array:

```
import cv2
img_cv2_aka_nparr = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
my_format = '.tiff'
retval, im_buffer = cv2.imencode(my_format, img_cv2_aka_nparr)
print type(im_buffer)
```

`im_buffer` is just another `numpy` array - it is not at all a TIFF-encoded bytestream! As far as I can tell, OpenCV images in python always behave like `numpy` arrays, and even look like `numpy` arrays via `type()`.

In fact, if you want to create a dummy "OpenCV image", you have to use `numpy` - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22921648/1021819

**Why is this, and how do I fix it? That is, how do I obtain an actual TIFF-encoded bytestream rather than another `numpy` array?**

Now I love `numpy`, but in this case I need the image to be readable by non-python services, so it needs to be in a commonly-available (preferably lossless) format (see list above).

(I've gone round the houses of embedding `numpy` within JSON and decided against it.)

I could use `PIL`/pillow, `scipy`, and some, but I am trying to minimize dependencies (i.e. so far only `cv2`, `numpy` and intrinsics).

Thanks!

Comment: "it is not at all a TIFF-encoded bytestream" -- Sure it is, contained in a single row numpy array.

Comment: @DanMašek Interesting... So if I return this over a RESTful interface I can just open it as a TIFF client-side?

Comment: Ya. You will want to call [`tostring()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) or `tobytes()` first.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks - that does it - please could you post an answer that I can accept? I do feel this falls in the cracks of the OpenCV/numpy/SO literature to date. (Also: Why..?!)

Comment: @DanMašek I've posted an answer but you deserve the credit so I will leave it open for a bit to see if you want to post an answer. Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: That's cool, feel free to accept your self-answer. Glad I could help you solve the problem :)

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks so much - I do feel bad but extremely grateful for you helping me get there! Seems so simple now... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/50630390/1021819 and building (but not very much) on the comment by Dan Masek, the required extra step is simply to use `im_buffer.tobytes()`, which returns a bytestring that can be sent through a stream.

Python OpenCV images do seem to be represented as pure `numpy` arrays. As pointed out by Dan Masek, the arrays can be transformed using `cv2.imencode()` into TIFF, PNG, BMP, JPG etc.

There is obviously some debate around choice of formats and compression. In the case above there was a preference for lossless compression, implying TIFF, BMP or PNG (still there will be debate). The python bindings to OpenCV have no tunable parameters for TIFF compression (unlike(?) the C++ bindings?), so it's not very easy to discover what *is* being done there. The compression level could apparently be better using other libraries but my aim was to minimize dependencies (see above).

A BMP-encoded image was no smaller than a TIFF one. PNG compression is tunable in python OpenCV, and setting

```
cv2.imencode('.png', nparr, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION),1])
```

has given the best size-speed trade-off so far. Thanks.