# How can i pass image itself (np.array) not path of it to zxing library for decode pdf417

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, zxing, pdf417

Code:

```
import zxing
from PIL import Image

reader = zxing.BarCodeReader()
path = 'C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/Uasa.png'
im = Image.open(path)

barcode = reader.decode(path)
print(barcode)
```

when i use code above work fine and return result:
BarCode(raw='P<E....

i need to use this code:

```
import zxing
import cv2

reader = zxing.BarCodeReader()
path = 'C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/Uasa.png'

img = cv2.imread (path)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

barcode = reader.decode(img)
print(barcode)
```

but this code return an error:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray

In another program i have image at base64 could help me somewhere here?

any body could help me with this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50630390/5320906) work for you?

Comment: no. i tried it and give me this error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZXing does not support passing an image directly as it is using an external application to process the barcode image. If you're not locked into using the ZXing library for decoding PDF417 barcodes you can take a look at the PyPI package [pdf417decoder](https://pypi.org/project/pdf417decoder/).

If you're starting with a Numpy array like in your example then you have to convert it to a PIL image first.

```
import cv2
import pdf417decoder
from PIL import Image

npimg = cv2.imread (path)
cv2.imshow('img', npimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)

img = Image.fromarray(npimg)
decoder = PDF417Decoder(img)

if (decoder.decode() > 0):
    print(decoder.barcode_data_index_to_string(0))
else:
    print("Failed to decode barcode.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing/blob/master/zxing/__init__.py#L34) you will see that what it does is call a java app with the provided path (Specifically `com.google.zxing.client.j2se.CommandLineRunner`).

If you need to pre-process your image then you will have to save it somewhere and pass the path to it to your library

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. i am using flask and cant save image in specific folder what should i do?

Comment: why cant you save the image? if you are on linux you should at the very least be able to write to `/dev/shm/` but don't forge to delete the image after you are done using it

Comment: why can't you write the image though? not even to `os.environ['TEMP']` ?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by:

```
path = os.getcwd()
# print(path)
writeStatus = cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'test.jpg'), pdf_image)
if writeStatus is True:
    print("image written")
else:
    print("problem")  # or raise exception, handle problem, etc.
sss = (os.path.join(path, 'test.jpg'))
# print(sss)
pp = sss.replace('\\', '/')
# print(pp)
reader = zxing.BarCodeReader()
barcode = reader.decode(pp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [zxing](https://pypi.org/project/zxing/) package is **not recommended**. It is just a command line tool to invoke Java ZXing libraries.

You should use [zxing-cpp](https://pypi.org/project/zxing-cpp/), which is a Python module built with ZXing C++ code. Here is the sample code:

```py
import cv2
import zxingcpp

img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
results = zxingcpp.read_barcodes(img)
for result in results:
    print("Found barcode:\n Text:    '{}'\n Format:   {}\n Position: {}"
        .format(result.text, result.format, result.position))
if len(results) == 0:
    print("Could not find any barcode.")
```