# How to send numpy arrays into zxing for detection, rather than a path to an image file?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, zxing

How to read the image through opencv and send it to zxing for detection instead of using the image path?

```
reader = zxing.BarCodeReader()
qrcode = reader.decode(img_path)
```

I want to use the code as below, but I won't do it in detail.

```
reader = zxing.BarCodeReader()
qrcode = reader.decode(cv2.imread(img_path))
```

Comment: which specific library/package of zxing for python do you use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i pass image itself not path of it to zxing library for decode pdf417](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790791/how-can-i-pass-image-itself-not-path-of-it-to-zxing-library-for-decode-pdf417)

Answer (score 0):

`zxing` supports PIL images so you can try:

```
qrcode = reader.decode(Image.open(img_path))`
```

If you need to use `opencv` images, first convert them to `PIL`:

```
qrcode = reader.decode(Image.fromarray(cv2.imread(img_path)))
```

Or you can write them to a temporary file, what `zxing` is actually doing if you pass a `PIL` image.

Links:

- [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)
- [zxing code](https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing/blob/master/zxing/__init__.py)